# Passing values between controllers by using the view object - JavaFX

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

When generating a multi view project with Gluon plugin for Ecplise, Netbeans or Intellij. It will be generating a view-class and a presenter-class. The view class looks like this for example:

```
public class ModelsView {

    public View getView() {
        try {
            View view = FXMLLoader.load(ModelsView.class.getResource("models.fxml"));
            return view;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
            return new View();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some way I can access all the private fields in this controller `models.fxml` by just creating a code line like this:

```
View view = new ModelsView().getView(); // Here I am inside another controller
```

Can I access for example the getter method from the presenter-class by using the `view` object ? The `view` object is static as I can see it because there is no `new` before `FXMLLoader.load(URL location)`

```
    public class ModelsPresenter {

    @FXML
    private View models;

    @FXML
    private @Getter TableView<String> tableView;

    public void initialize() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heretic I am not using JavaFX from Gluon my configuration is jdk1.8.0_191 with derby in Netbeans 8.2 The code I am posting is my Model class PWData and the TableViewController just grabs the data from the derby DB The real important code is the initialize section of the TableViewController

```
public class PWData {

    private final StringProperty ID;
    private final StringProperty website;
    private final StringProperty un;
    private final StringProperty pw;
    private final StringProperty sq;
    private final StringProperty sans;
    private final StringProperty notes;

    public PWData(String ID,String website,String un,String pw,String sq,String sans,String notes) {
        this.ID = new SimpleStringProperty(ID);
        this.website = new SimpleStringProperty(website);
        this.un = new SimpleStringProperty(un);
        this.pw = new SimpleStringProperty(pw);
        this.sq = new SimpleStringProperty(sq);
        this.sans = new SimpleStringProperty(sans);
        this.notes = new SimpleStringProperty(notes);
    }

    public String getID() {// 0
        return ID.get();
    }
    public void setID(String ID){// 0
        this.ID.set(ID);
    }
    public StringProperty IDProperty(){// 0
        return ID;
    }

    public String getWebSite() {// 1
        return website.get();
    }
    public void setwebsite(String website){// 1
        this.website.set(website);
    }
    public StringProperty websiteProperty(){// 1
        return website;
    }

    public String getUNName() {// 2
        return un.get();
    }
    public void setun(String un){// 2
        this.un.set(un);
    }
    public StringProperty unProperty(){// 2
        return un;
    }

    public String getPW() {// 3
        return pw.get();
    }
    public void setpw(String pw){// 3
        this.pw.set(pw);
    }
    public StringProperty pwProperty(){// 3
        return pw;
    }

    public String getSQName() {// 4
        return sq.get();
    }
    public void setsq(String sq){// 4
        this.sq.set(sq);
    }
    public StringProperty sqProperty(){// 4
        return sq;
    }

    public String getSANS() {// 5
        return sans.get();
    }
    public void setsans(String sans){// 5
        this.sans.set(sans);
    }
    public StringProperty sansProperty(){// 5
        return sans;
    }

    public String getNotes() {// 6
        return notes.get();
    }
    public void setnotes(String notes){// 6
        this.notes.set(notes);
    }
    public StringProperty notesProperty(){// 6
        return notes;
    }

public class TableViewController implements Initializable {

@FXML Pane tableviewPane,signinPane,detailviewPane;
@FXML private TableView<PWData> table;// NOTE CONSTRUCTION see Observable Value
@FXML private TableColumn<PWData,String> IDCol;
@FXML private TableColumn<PWData,String> websiteCol;
@FXML private TableColumn<PWData,String> unCol;
@FXML private TableColumn<PWData,String> pwCol;


String SQL_PWDataTable = "create table PWData ("
+ "ID     int not null generated always as identity "
+ "         (start with 100,increment by 1),"
+ "website  varchar(50) not null, un varchar(40) not null, "
+ "pw  varchar(40) not null, sq varchar(80) not null, "
+ "sans varchar(80) not null, notes varchar(260) not null,"
+ "primary key (ID) )";

String dbName="PWKeep";
public Stage stage;
String conURL = "jdbc:derby:C:/A_DerbyPWKeeper/DBName/" + dbName;
public static String strID;
KeyCode kc;

@FXML
private void onPress(KeyEvent ev) throws IOException{
    kc = ev.getCode();
    if(kc == KeyCode.ESCAPE){
        onBack(null);
    }   
}

private void MakeTable() throws SQLException, IOException{
    if (!tableExists( SignInController.con, "PWData")){
        //System.out.println ("Creating table PWData");
        SignInController.stmnt = SignInController.con.createStatement();
        SignInController.stmnt.execute(SQL_PWDataTable );
        SignInController.stmnt.close();
    }else{
        //System.out.println("PWData already created");
    }
    ReadFromDB();
}

// Does the table EXISTS 
private static boolean tableExists ( Connection con, String table ) {
    int numRows = 0;

    try {
        DatabaseMetaData dbmd = con.getMetaData();
        // Note the args to getTables are case-sensitive!
        ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables( null, "APP", table.toUpperCase(), null);
    while( rs.next()) ++numRows;

    }catch(SQLException e){
        String theError = e.getSQLState();
        System.out.println("Can't query DB metadata: " + theError );
        System.exit(1);
    }
        return numRows > 0;
}

private void ReadFromDB() throws SQLException{
    SignInController.stmnt = SignInController.con.createStatement();
    ObservableList<PWData> TableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try (ResultSet rs = SignInController.stmnt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PWData") // Get all DB data
    //int rowCount = 0;
    ) {
        while (rs.next()){// Add data to observableArrayList TableData
            //rowCount++;
            TableData.add(new PWData(rs.getString("ID"),rs.getString("website")
                    ,rs.getString("un"),rs.getString("pw"),rs.getString("sq"),rs.getString("sans"),rs.getString("notes")));
        }   //System.out.println("Row Count "+rowCount);// Useful for Printing for further development

        PropertyValueFactory<PWData, String> IDCellValueFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("ID");
        IDCol.setCellValueFactory(IDCellValueFactory);
        PropertyValueFactory<PWData, String> WebSiteCellValueFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("website");
        websiteCol.setCellValueFactory(WebSiteCellValueFactory);
        PropertyValueFactory<PWData, String> UNCellValueFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("un");
        unCol.setCellValueFactory(UNCellValueFactory);
        PropertyValueFactory<PWData, String> PWCellValueFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("pw");
        pwCol.setCellValueFactory(PWCellValueFactory);
        Collections.sort(TableData, (p1, p2)-> p1.getWebSite().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getWebSite()));
        // Line of Code above Sorts websiteCol alpha
        if(TableData.size() < 14) {// Format TableView to display Vertical ScrollBar
            table.setPrefWidth(838);
        }else {
            table.setPrefWidth(855);
        }   table.setItems(TableData);
        SignInController.stmnt.close();
    }
}

@FXML
private void onBack(ActionEvent e) throws IOException{

    stage = (Stage)tableviewPane.getScene().getWindow();
    signinPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("signin.fxml")); 
    Scene scene = new Scene(signinPane);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("pwkeeper.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(scene); 
    stage.show();
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.centerOnScreen();
}

@FXML 
private void onAdd(ActionEvent e) throws IOException{

    stage = (Stage)tableviewPane.getScene().getWindow();
    detailviewPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("detailview.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(detailviewPane);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("pwkeeper.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(scene); 
    stage.show();
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.centerOnScreen();
}

private void MakeConn() throws SQLException, IOException{
    SignInController.con = DriverManager.getConnection(conURL);
}

@FXML // This DROPS the MasterPW TABLE when the Reset Password is selected
private void onDrop(ActionEvent e) throws SQLException, IOException{
    SignInController.stmnt = SignInController.con.createStatement();
    SignInController.stmnt.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE MasterPW");
    SignInController.stmnt.close();
    onBack(null);
}

private void showTableDataDetails(PWData info) throws IOException{
    if (info != null) {
        info =  (PWData) table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        strID = info.getID();
        onAdd(null);
    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    try {
        MakeTable();
    } catch (SQLException | IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TableViewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends PWData>
        observable,PWData oldValue, PWData newValue) -> {
    try {
        showTableDataDetails((PWData) newValue); // When a row of the table is Selected call
        // Proper Construction                   // showTableDataDetails method  
    } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TableViewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    });
}
```

I am a little unsure of what you are trying to do but I would suggest you focus on the use of ObservableValue and Listeners You can download the entire code
[At GitHub HERE](https://github.com/e-d-n/PW-Keeper)

Comment: @Heretic It helps every one if you comment about the Answer I do not care about up or down VOTES